# Can I pass a list of arguments using equal sign (=) syntax?

Tags: python, argparse

I can pass a list of arguments to my script with `argparse` using:

```
parser.add_argument('--myarg', type=str.lower, nargs='+', choices=['a','b','c'])
```

and running:

```
myscript --myarg a b
```

However, if I use an equal sign syntax:

```
myscript --myarg=a b
```

it will throw an error because it thinks `b` is a positional argument. Using a custom `action` also does not seem to work since `argparse` does not collect `b` at all.

Comment: You would need to use quotes: `myscript --myarg="a b"`.  This has to do with how the shell processes the command line, not with how `argparse` handles the resulting arguments.

Comment: `--myarg a b` are three separate arguments to the script, while `--myarg="a b"` is a *single* argument that `argparse` splits into `--myarg` and `a b` itself; you would also be responsible for splitting `a b` into separate strings `a` and `b` yourself.

Comment: I would prefer the multiple arguments, as you can then distinguish between `--myarg a "b c"` and `--myarg "a b" c` much more easily than you could by trying to encode the two arguments into a single string.

Comment: The '=' only works for one argument, the string that follows.